# How to make malloc return always the same adress?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

When running several times the same C programm, the address returned by malloc is always different.
Is it possible to force Linux/gcc to always get the same adresses for a memory allocation ?

Thanks,
Fred

Comment: Why does it need to, out of interest?

Comment: Why do you care what address is returned?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: Sounds like a [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/), or do you aks just because you are curious?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238457/disable-and-re-enable-address-space-layout-randomization-only-for-myself) regarding enabling/disabling address space layout randomization on Linux.

Comment: @dbush if ASLR is disabled, does it guarantee that the first malloc will return the same address on successive runs?

Comment: Why do you need this? Even if it's for a test (unit, or any other kind), it really should not depend on the value returned malloc, other than checking if it's other than null (allocation failure).

Comment: @MichaelWalz I would say no.  Some library thread/s in a race to the malloc mutex... and you're back with unreliable repeatability.

Comment: BTW, gcc is a compiler. It has nothing to do with returning memory address.

Comment: I have an array of structures, each element has an id and severals pointers and offsets. I had an instability, some runs work fine and other ones failed. I dumped the content of the elements to check the offsets which must be constant from one run to the other. As the pointers always change, the diff is difficult. I agree that a good solution could be to dump only the offsets but I'd like to know if there is a way to make the pointers constant.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to assign the same address everytime, as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534874/malloc-a-struct-at-a-specific-point-in-memory) question. However what you're doing is questionable, and it is most likely the case there's a better way of doing what you want to do, rather than always getting the same address.

Comment: The same physical address, that is not always the same value the malloc function returns! It's possible to obtain physical addresses using other functions than malloc.

Comment: Some IPC functions may be used to obtain and manage same memory areas between different processes.